# several hard drives and partitions

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

If there are two physically separate hard drives, should they be treated as two pre-defined partitions?

If yes:

- should they be treated as two primary
  partitions (including one or two of
  them can become extended partition(s)
  and be further subdivided into
  logical partitions)?
- Or they (or one part of each) can be
  treated as two logical partitions of
  a extended partition?

Thanks!

---

I intended to ask if there can be a primary/logical partition that are partially on both hard drives? And if there can be a logical partition on a hard drive and another logical partition on another hard, and the two logical partitions belong to the same extended partition? I guess the answers to both questions are no?

Comment: They should be turned into two PVs and added to the same VG.

Comment: Thanks! But What do PV and VG mean?

Comment: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/

Answer (score 1):

Every drive is capable of having up to four primary partitions.  So with two drives you could have up to eight primary partitions.

On each drive, if you make one of those partitions into an extended partition, then you can have N logical partitions.

For instance:

```
Drive 1: hda
 hda1 - Primary
 hda2 - Primary
 hda3 - Primary
 hda4 - Extended
    hda5 - Logical
    ...
    hda9 - Logical

Drive 2: hdb
 hdb1 - Primary
 hdb2 - Extended
    hdb5 - Logical
    hdb6 - Logical
    ...
 hdb3 - Primary
 hdb4 - Primary
```

Is but one example of a number of different possibilities.

Comment: The "four primary partitions" is a limitation of the MS-DOS partition table. If your firmware and OS are capable of using them, there are alternate partition table formats that do not have this limitation.

Comment: @Ignacio: could you point me to some websites with information about the limitation of "four primary partitions" does and does not exist for different partition table formats? I'd like to know more. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I intended to ask if there can be a primary/logical partition that are partially on both hard drives? And if there can be a logical partition on a hard drive and another logical partition on another hard, and the two logical partitions belong to the same extended partition? I guess the answers to both questions are no?

Comment: @Tim: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_partition_map

Comment: Oh, another caveat is that the extended partition should be the last primary partition; some operating systems do not like the partition table if it isn't. And *never* create more than one per drive.